# Combining ADSL's valid IP and LTE's high upload bandwidth

Tags: internet, routing, bandwidth, adsl, cellular-internet

I have an ADSL connection with 10/1 Mbps download/upload speed and a valid IPv4 address (i.e., addressable from the internet). Also, there is a Debian server on my network that is running a GitLab CE server. By forwarding certain ports in the ADSL modem, clients are able to reach the GitLab server using the IP address of the ADSL modem.

Since 1Mbps upload speed is really slow, I need to find a way to increase the bandwidth. I was wondering if a cellular (LTE) modem with 30+/30+ Mbps download/upload speed could help. The problem is that this connection will **not have** a valid IPv4 address and the external clients cannot send their requests to the cellular modem directly.

Now, is there any way to attach both modems to the network and force the server to use the cellular connection for its responses even though it would always receive the requests from the ADSL connection? I am trying to increase the upload bandwidth of the server and it is not a matter of security. Therefore, I don't care if some responses use the ADSL connection as long as it does not become a bottleneck.

If not, is there any other way to accomplish this task? My question might seem similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/981642/channel-bonding-adsl-lte-with-azure-ec2) but I don't care which connection gets utilized as long as upload speed is increased.

My current idea is to buy a light VPS with a valid IP address, setup an always-on IPsec over L2TP connection between the GitLab server and the VPS using the cellular connection, and forward all the traffic from the required ports on the VPS to the GitLab server. Would this work?

Comment: Sounds like it's pretty simple, you just have to set your routing table to route all packets to your LTE modem. A simple `ip route default via {LTE gateway} dev lte0` or something should do the trick. Assuming that your LTE provider doesn't block the traffic. It would also mess up any carrier grade NAT they have.

Comment: I set the gateway to the LTE modem but it did not work. Perhaps because the NAT was established in the ADSL modem while the LTE modem did not know how to route the response.
I decided to use a VPS for now. However, finding a solution to this problem could be beneficial to others.

Comment: ADSL modem NAT? Sounds wrong.

Comment: Maybe DNAT? It seems to me that the ADSL modem/router knew where the request came from (the IP address of the requester) but the LTE modem had no idea. Therefore, when the server sent the packets to the LTE modem, it did not know where the packets should be sent to and just dropped it. Also, it should be mentioned that the requesters are usually behind their own NAT too (no public IP).